# why don't cron jobs in /etc/cron.d directory appear in crontab -e?

Tags: linux, cron, ubuntu-14.04, crontab

I do `sudo crontab -e` and see a bunch of cronjobs. If a cron exists in `/etc/cron.d` but not in `sudo crontab -e` does that mean it's not being ran? Or is it being ran but just isn't showing up for whatever reason in `sudo crontab -e`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are different kinds of `cron` locations, although they are handled by the same daemon (`cron`).

The configuration that you find under `/etc/cron.d` is system-wide and it's run with the user that you specify just before the command, which is nice.

But what happens when a non-(root|administrator) user wants to set their own crons without root-user intervention? They use `crontab`, which stores their crons in `/var/spool/cron` (and will run their scripts with their usernames, with no possibility to choose).

As you may see, the locations are different, thus they are different kind of crons; if you use `crontab -l` or `crontab -e` you'll see those crontabs defined under the path I mentioned above. The ones specified in `/etc/cron.d` are listed using standard tools like `ls`, edited with `vi`, etc.